# xdebug_info() shows old values

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

My Xdebug doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.4. I get the error:

> [Step Debug] Creating socket for 'localhost:9009', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).

I have already made some changes in the `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` file. Restarting Apache via `service apache2 restart` or via `/etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload` does not change anything for `xdebug_info()`. The new values are only displayed after restarting the computer.

Does `xdebug_info()` show a mirage? Or are the values ​​real at this point? Which blockage do I have to fix instead?

Answer (score 2):

`xdebug_info()` shows the current accurate, and real values.